# DAYOFWEEK function for SEDE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, odata

The [specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/odbc-scalar-functions-transact-sql) on SQL Azure mention ODBC date and time functions, namely to transform a date to weekday.

Currently, using DAYOFWEEK results in an error message:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(LastActivityDate) FROM Posts Limit 1;
```

> Error: 'DAYOFWEEK' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DAYOFWEEK is a MySQL function (likewise for LIMIT) - Azure uses Microsoft's TSQL functionality - you want [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP 1
       DATEPART(dw, LastActivityDate) 
  FROM Posts
```

Reference:

- [TOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link to the documentation that you gave, and they illustrate the usage as:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    {fn DAYOFWEEK( LastActivityDate )}
FROM Posts
```

Example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/716136